# How to allow the client to switch git branches on a website? (*without technical knowledge, for QA)

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch, devops

I need to find a way for our client(s) to switch branches on a project (website) without technical knowledge.
We push our features/fixes to separate branches, but when we need to get the client's approval - we have to merge them to a main development branch & pull to a UAT (test) server. When it's all approved we merge the development branch to the production branch & pull to the production servers.
The problem is when we merge more then one branch, 4 for example, and the client only accepts 2 of them. In that case we have 2 options:

1. Fix the other 2 or wait until they are accepted.
2. Play with git to undo the merge & merge again only the approved branches.

I'm not happy with both of the options.

Is there any simple way to allow the client to just switch the branches on the UAT (test) server so we only merge after approval?

*By "client" I mean - Someone who has no technical knowledge at all, who doesn't know what linux/ssh/git/... is.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to provide that functionality yourself. How this would work highly depends on how you actually deploy things. Git has nothing to do with that, and there is not anything Git actually does or know about the deployment.

Comment: I know. I was hoping that there are other tools for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the two options you thought, there have another way:

1. Create a branch `temp` from `development` (same usage as `development`) for client use.
2. Merge the branches you worked into `temp`.
3. After client approved part of branches, then you can merge these approved branches into `development` and then merge `development` into `production`.

Comment: I don't like the first part of your answer because no, it's not legitimate to ask the client to use git commands or SSH or stuff that requires technical knowledge. But - the second suggestion is actually a great idea! Now I only need to find a way to automate the process with deployment scripts & it should solve the case. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, it's depend on your requirement. I updated my answer. Since it help you solve the problem you can mark it.